IIS throwing error : .NET Runtime at IP 0x00007FFA58796C1D (0x00007FFA58530000) with exit code 0xe0004743
We have a web application hosted in IIS and getting the following error intermittent and on restart it gets resolved.
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 8.0.424.16909
.NET Version: 8.0.4
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 0x00007FFA58796C1D (0x00007FFA58530000) with exit code 0xe0004743.

We tried having permission check , the application pool checked for 32 bit or 64 bit. it was a 64 bit application and also permisssion on the logs files also checked , necessary permissions were there.
Only restart of application pool resolved the issue.


We tried having permission check , the application pool checked for 32
bit or 64 bit. it was a 64 bit application and also permisssion on the
logs files also checked , necessary permissions were there. Only
restart of application pool resolved the issue.

Based on your error message and description its hard to directly conclude into any specific solution. Because, merely application log files might not be enough to investigate the issue.
When any error message like "The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime" has been thrown, it apparently seems very generic and also might point to unmanaged code.
In this scenario, only application log is not sufficient. Additionally, we might need to check IIS log, Event viewer log.
As you also said, it happend intermittently, above logs also may not help to find the main issue. In that case, application dump also may required. So, these logs might contains sensitive information, as a result sharing those files either in stack overflow or other community might not be recommended or hard to assist on this.
It would be great if you really want to check the issue or proceed to the soltuion, you could create a internal support request. Thus, relevant team could assist you on this.
According to my experience, first check your application code, and watch them in which context you are getting that error, it might help you to narrow down the context of occurence. But yeah, best to deal with the internal support team.
Note: I would recommend you to use this Debug dignostic tool to investigate your issue. But cannot offer any specific solution to resolve it.

Thank will try with the Debug diagnostic tool. This behavior is only observed in .Net core 8.

Got your point, you could try the steps I've explained.
